# Separate Strings Into A Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm working with data that looks like this:

```
id <- c("673506", "624401", "674764")
bills <- c("sb 1181; ab 573; ab 2697", 
           "sb 1181; ab 573; ab 2697; ab 2448", 
           "sb 292; ab 497")

df <- data.frame(id, bills)
df
```

How can I transform the data so that the data is long from, the IDs repeat per every corresponding bill separated by a semi-colon?

Such that the data looks like this:

[image: desired outcome]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
 separate_rows(df, bills, sep = ";\\s+")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  id     bills  
  <chr>  <chr>  
1 673506 sb 1181
2 673506 ab 573 
3 673506 ab 2697
4 624401 sb 1181
5 624401 ab 573 
6 624401 ab 2697
7 624401 ab 2448
8 674764 sb 292 
9 674764 ab 497
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach.

```
do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, df$id, strsplit(df$bills, '; ')))) |>
  as.data.frame() |> setNames(names(df))
#       id   bills
# 1 673506 sb 1181
# 2 673506  ab 573
# 3 673506 ab 2697
# 4 624401 sb 1181
# 5 624401  ab 573
# 6 624401 ab 2697
# 7 624401 ab 2448
# 8 674764  sb 292
# 9 674764  ab 497
```